# Light not passing through all windows

Tags: lighting, windows

[image]I am creating a room using archimesh. And have applied auto holes

I have a room with three windows, all set up the same, all using the same material. If I place all the windows in the correct position light only shines through one of them.

If I remove the windows from the building and then only place one in position at a time then 2 out of the three allow light to pass through.

I cant seem to find out what is going on?

Any ideas

Thanks so much[image]

[image]